# Baked procedural normal map reflect light only some sides

Tags: texturing, node-editor, normals, normal-map, procedural

I have baked my Nodes procedural normal texture via cycle rendering and I get some of the results works.
However, It worked only for some sides. Not sure why? Does anyone have any clues? Pretty sure my normal map didn't bake correctly.

Blender 2.92

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/5woTU.jpg **(GIF HERE!)****

[image]

This is my Normal map

[image]

**Blend File is here:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qIzquPNuWsEd8XQ29WJxgKZJhy4XVdRK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question please? (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)  Your normal map is messed up so your bake probably failed but we can't tell why from these screen shots.

Comment: @MartyFouts The https://blend-exchange.com/ stop uploading through the upload 2 times. The first was "Internal server error". I think the file size might be over 200 MB. However, I uploaded it through google drive. Thank you!

Comment: That's because you packed a 268mb HDR image into it.  Don't think you needed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! It was the node graph that I connect to the Bump Map into the Normal Map then Output to the shader. (Normal => Color => Normal => Shader) Rearrange my node is the solution